# How to add string in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new, and I use Ruby on Rails 4 to create a web app.
I stucked in a SyntaxError.
Here's the code

```rb
<% if c.username.nil? %><br>
<%= puts "somebody" %><br>
<% else %><br>
<%= link_to c.username %><br>
<% end %><br>
```

All I want is display HTML content...And I know code No.2 is wrong.But I really don't know how to fix it in the index.html.erb
Thx,please help me

Comment: It would help if you added the error you are getting to the question...

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
<%= "somebody" %>
```

Not

```
<%= puts "somebody" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you can do this

```
<% if c.username.nil? %>
  <br>
  <%= "somebody" %>
  <br>
<% else %><br>
  <%= link_to c.username %>
  <br>
<% end %>
<br>
```

or you can save your formatted html in a variable like

```
<% if c.username.nil? %>
  <% @str = "<br> somebody <br>".html_safe %>
  <%= @str %>
<% else %><br>
  <%= link_to c.username %>
  <br>
<% end %>
<br>
```

you can also do interpolation

```
<% if c.username.nil? %>
  <%= "<br> #{'somebody'} <br>".html_safe %>
<% else %><br>
  <%= link_to c.username %>
  <br>
<% end %>
<br>
```